# If a function interpolates as a polynomial on arithmetic progressions, is it a polynomial function?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, interpolation

Let $F$ be a finite field of size $q$, and let $d<q$. It is well known that for every sequence $x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_{d+1}$ of distinct elements in $F$, there is a sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_d$ of interpolation coefficients such that $f(x_0)=\sum_{i=1,\ldots,d+1}a_i f(x_i)$ for every polynomial  function $f$ on $F$ of degree at most d. For a general function $f$ on $F$ that satisfies the above equality, we say that $f$ interpolates well on $x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_{d+1}$.

It is quite easy to verify that a function $f$ that interpolates well on all sequences of distinct elements must be a polynomial function of degree at most $d$. It is also not difficult to see that if $f$ interpolates well on the arithmetic progressions, then it must be a polynomial function of degree at most $d$, in the case where $F$ is a prime field.

My question is: is this still true when the size of the field, $q$, is a prime power?

[Also, is there a more general characterization of sets of interpolation sequences which imply low-degree?]

Comment: Can you clarify what "the arithmetic progressions" are in a finite field? Do you mean sequences of the form $x_0, x_0+k, \dots, x_0+(d+1)k$? If so, I imagine one runs into trouble when $q=p^r$ and $k$ is a multiple of $p$ (or maybe $p^{r-1}$).

Comment: I'm not sure I caught all the nuances you want. But *every* function from $F=\Bbb{F}_q$ to itself is a *polynomial function*, so??

Comment: As Greg Martin explained, every arithmetic progression of elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$, $q=p^m$, has period $p$. Please clarify.

Comment: @GregMartin, I mean a sequence of the form $x_0, x_0+y, x_0+2y,..x_0+(d+1)y$, where $y$ is an element of the field. For this to make sense, we should assume that d+1 is smaller than the characteristic of the field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I mean a polynomial function *of degree at most d*